# How to pass an object from Stateful Widget to its State? (not in Widget)

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to pass a User object from my stateful widget, to its state.

```
class NavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final User user;
  NavBar({this.user});
  @override
  NavBarState createState() => NavBarState();
}


class NavBarState extends State<NavBar> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  final List<Widget> _children = [
    CalendarWidget(),
    HomeWidget(),
    MessagingWidget(),
    ProfilePage(user: user)
  ];
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

All other solutions say to use widget.user like `ProfilePage(user: widget.user)` but that throws error:

```
Only static members can be accessed in initializers.dart(implicit_this_reference_in_initializer)
```

**How can I access User object in the state of NavBar so I can send it to ProfilePage()?**

Comment: initialize `_children` inside `initState()` method - if you do that you will be able to use `ProfilePage(user: widget.user)`

Comment: What's you're asking for should not be done. Create _children inside _build_ or _initState_and only there

Answer (score 0):

you can use `widget.yourObjectsName` to access StateFul widget's Object in its state

you can use any property of Stateful Widgets from its state by widget property of state which gives reference to state's Widget properties.